# What is this succulent with textured grey-green foliage?

Tags: identification, succulents

Please help me identify this succulent. It was given to me by my neighbor, and has a velvety texture. The plastic pot is about 3-3.5".

The small pinkish-orange circle in top view pic, resting on soil, is a Jade plant clipping that dropped in from plant stand above it. It has nothing to do with identification. It is not a snail, or bug or part if this plant.

[image: Full front view pic1]

[image: Top view pic2]

[image: Side view #2 pic3]

[image: Angled side view pic4]

Answer (score 4):

This is [*Crassula falcata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassula_falcata), or propeller plant. It's a popular collectors succulent and houseplant due to the striking and unique leaf arrangement. In good conditions, the plant will flower (more commonly outdoors than in).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @J. Musser , do you happen to know if the browning on the larger, lower leaves is normal? Or a sign of poor care? Is there a solution? They were outdoors up until a few days ago

Comment: @ChristyB. It depends. If the plants are growing in low nutrient mix, they can tend to lose lower leaves as new ones come in. Or if it's very dry